# How to retrieve a set of objects through multiple levels of SQLAlchemy relationships?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the following setup how do I retrieve a set of SensorDatas from all of a Car's Tires?

A Car has many Tires and a Tire has one SensorData, so in SQL I'd do something like

```sql
SELECT sd.* 
FROM Car AS c 
    INNER JOIN Tire AS t ON c.id = t.car_id 
    INNER JOIN SensorData AS sd ON t.id = sd.tire_id
```

```py
class Car(Base):
    pass

class Tire(Base):
    car = relationship("Car", backref="tires")

class SensorData(Base):
    tire = relationship("Tire", backref=backref("sensor_data", uselist=False))
```

I'm guessing there's a more elegant way to get all the SensorData's than the following, but I can't find it.

```py
tires = Car.query.get(1).tires
sensor_datas = [sensor_data for tire.sensor_data in tires]
```

Can anyone advise on a better approach?  I'm imagining I should be able to do something like

```py
sensor_datas = Car.query.get(1).sensor_datas

    OR

sensor_datas = Car.query.get(1).tires.sensor_data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These solutions will return a read only `sensor_datas` attribute on `Car`, see comments for more info:

```
class Car(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # results in a collection of sensor_data objects. This method is the 
    # cleanest reading by far, but behaves a little differently from the
    # other two in terms of how the collection is constructed. Accessing
    # the association proxy causes sqlalchemy to query the tire table for
    # for the `Car`'s `Tire`s and then iterates over each one, accessing
    # its `sensor_data` attribute to construct the collection on `Car`.
    # With the lazy loading defaults, this resulted in 5 queries to 
    # construct the relationship, so depending on how you need to use it
    # you might consider some sort of eager loading.
    sensor_datas_aprox = association_proxy('tires', 'sensor_data')

    # Joins Tire and SensorData. TBH the docs only mention
    # using secondary in context of m:n relationship, but 
    # this seems to work OK.
    sensor_datas_rel = relationship(
        'SensorData',
        secondary='join(Tire, SensorData)',
        viewonly=True
    )

    # a query enabled property, queries for the data on 
    # access, pretty self explanatory.
    @property
    def sensor_datas_prop(self):
        return object_session(self).query(SensorData).\
            join(Tire).filter(
                Tire.car_id == self.id,
                SensorData.tire_id == Tire.id
            ).all()


class Tire(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('car.id'))
    car = relationship("Car", backref="tires")


class SensorData(Base):
    tire_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tire.id'), primary_key=True)
    tire = relationship("Tire", backref=backref("sensor_data", uselist=False))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Session()
    for _ in range(2):
        car = Car()
        car.tires = [Tire(sensor_data=SensorData()) for _ in range(4)]
        s.add(car)
    s.commit()
    for car in s.query(Car):
        print('*' * 100)
        print(car.sensor_datas_rel)
        print(car.sensor_datas_prop)
        print(car.sensor_datas_aprox)
```

Output:

```
****************************************************************************************************
[SensorData(tire_id=1), SensorData(tire_id=2), SensorData(tire_id=3), SensorData(tire_id=4)]
[SensorData(tire_id=1), SensorData(tire_id=2), SensorData(tire_id=3), SensorData(tire_id=4)]
[SensorData(tire_id=1), SensorData(tire_id=2), SensorData(tire_id=3), SensorData(tire_id=4)]
****************************************************************************************************
[SensorData(tire_id=5), SensorData(tire_id=6), SensorData(tire_id=7), SensorData(tire_id=8)]
[SensorData(tire_id=5), SensorData(tire_id=6), SensorData(tire_id=7), SensorData(tire_id=8)]
[SensorData(tire_id=5), SensorData(tire_id=6), SensorData(tire_id=7), SensorData(tire_id=8)]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had been wondering about whether I could use the secondary/association stuff that's listed for many-to-many.  

And seeing how to project SensorData out I knew how to do, but don't understand why the filter must be specified.  Why can't it use the existing relationships and avoid the repetition?   Put another way, if I've already specified foreign keys / relationships, why must they be respecified?

Comment: No.  It's why must I specify foreign keys and  the table joins in filter() for sensor_datas_props?

Comment: Or why must I specify a primaryjoin on a relationship and then repeat the same info in the filter() call in sensor_data_props?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but association_proxy might be another alternative

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html

Comment: I considered the association proxy option myself but discounted as I didn't think it would handle transforming the 1 to 1 relationship between `Tire` and `SensorData` into a collection on `Car`, but after giving it a try, it seems it does. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Just to be clear, these are all totally separate methods, you wouldn't define more than one of them as they are all trying to do the same thing. The property based one is just a query, so it needs to include the filter and join to get the appropriate data. It's not related at all to the relationship, so defining `secondary` on the relationship has nothing to do with the property. It's just a demo of 3 separate and distinct methods that can achieve what you are after.